# Skip list -based Map in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, skip-list

Now I have [this result](https://github.com/coderodde/SkipListMap.java).

## Code

**`com.github.coderodde.util.SkipListMap.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.SortedMap;
import java.util.function.BiConsumer;
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Function;

public final class SkipListMap<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V>
          implements SortedMap<K, V> {
    
    /**
     * The default coin probability.
     */
    public static final double DEFAULT_COIN_PROBABILITY = 0.5;
    
    /**
     * The minimum coin probability;
     */
    private static final double MINIMUM_COIN_PROBABILITY = 0.1;
    
    /**
     * The maximum coin probability;
     */
    private static final double MAXIMUM_COIN_PROBABILITY = 0.9;

    /**
     * The maximum level of this skip list.
     */
    private static final int MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_LEVELS = 20;
    
    /**
     * Implements the actual skip list node.
     * 
     * @param <K> the key type.
     * @param <V> the value type.
     */
    private static final class SkipListMapNode<K extends Comparable<? super K>,
                                               V> {
        K key;
        V value;
        SkipListMapNode<K, V>[] forward;
        
        SkipListMapNode(K key, V value, int levels) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.forward = new SkipListMapNode[levels];
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format(
                    "[key = '%s', value = '%s', forward list size = '%d']", 
                    Objects.toString(key), 
                    Objects.toString(value),
                    forward.length);
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * The number of keys stored in this skip list.
     */
    private int size = 0;
    
    /**
     * The number of levels in this skip list.
     */
    private int numberOfLevels = 1;
    /**
     * The header node.
     */
    private SkipListMapNode<K, V> header = 
            new SkipListMapNode<>(null, 
                                  null,
                                  MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_LEVELS);
    
    /**
     * Used in {@link #put(java.lang.Comparable, java.lang.Object)} and 
     * {@link #remove(java.lang.Object)}.
     */
    private final SkipListMapNode<K, V>[] update = 
        new SkipListMapNode[MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_LEVELS];
    
    /**
     * The random number generator.
     */
    private final Random random;
    
    /**
     * The coin probability.
     */
    private final double p;
    
    public SkipListMap(double coinProbability, Random random) {
        this.p = validateCoinProbability(coinProbability);
        this.random = Objects.requireNonNull(random, "Input Random is null.");
    }
    
    public SkipListMap(double coinProbability, long seed) {
        this(coinProbability, new Random(seed));
    }
    
    public SkipListMap(double coinProbability) {
        this(coinProbability, new Random());
    }
    
    public SkipListMap(Random random) {
        this.random = Objects.requireNonNull(random, "Input Random is null.");
        this.p = DEFAULT_COIN_PROBABILITY;
    }
    
    public SkipListMap(long seed) {
        this.random = new Random(seed);
        this.p = DEFAULT_COIN_PROBABILITY;
    }
    
    public SkipListMap() {
        this.random = new Random();
        this.p = DEFAULT_COIN_PROBABILITY;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;}

    @Override
    public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
        return accessNode((K) key) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        SkipListMapNode<K, V> node = accessNode((K) key);
        return node == null ? null : node.value;
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        
        SkipListMapNode<K, V> x = header;
        
        for (int i = numberOfLevels - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            while (x.forward[i] != null && 
                   x.forward[i].key.compareTo(key) < 0) {
                
                x = x.forward[i];
            }
            
            update[i] = x;
        }
        
        x = x.forward[0];
        
        if (x != null && x.key.compareTo(key) == 0) {
            V oldValue = x.value;
            x.value = value;
            return oldValue;
        }
        
        // Insert the unpresent key:
        int newNumberOfLevels = getRandomNumberOfLevels();
        
        if (newNumberOfLevels > numberOfLevels) {
            for (int i = numberOfLevels; i < newNumberOfLevels; i++) {
                update[i] = header;
            }
            
            numberOfLevels = newNumberOfLevels;
        }
        
        x = new SkipListMapNode<>(key, value, numberOfLevels);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLevels; i++) {
            x.forward[i] = update[i].forward[i];
            update[i].forward[i] = x;
        }
        
        size++;
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public V remove(Object key) {
        
        SkipListMapNode<K, V> x = header;
        
        for (int i = numberOfLevels - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            while (x.forward[i] != null && 
                   x.forward[i].key.compareTo((K) key) < 0) {
                
                x = x.forward[i];
            }
            
            update[i] = x;
        }
        
        x = x.forward[0];
        
        if (x == null || !x.key.equals(key)) {
            return null;
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLevels; i++) {
            if (update[i].forward[i] == null || 
               !update[i].forward[i].equals(x)) {
                break;
            }
            
            update[i].forward[i] = x.forward[i];
        }
        
        while (numberOfLevels > 0 
                && header.forward[numberOfLevels - 1] == null) {
            numberOfLevels--;
        }
        
        size--;
        return x.value;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        size = 0;
        numberOfLevels = 1;
        header = new SkipListMapNode<>(null, null, MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_LEVELS);
    }

    @Override
    public Comparator<? super K> comparator() {
        throwUnsupported();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public SortedMap<K, V> subMap(K fromKey, K toKey) {
        throwUnsupported();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public SortedMap<K, V> headMap(K toKey) {
        throwUnsupported();
        return null;    
    }

    @Override
    public SortedMap<K, V> tailMap(K fromKey) {
        throwUnsupported();
        return null;    
    }

    @Override
    public K firstKey() {
        throwUnsupported();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public K lastKey() {
        throwUnsupported();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<K> keySet() {
        throwUnsupported();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<V> values() {
        throwUnsupported();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Entry<K, V>> entrySet() {
        throwUnsupported();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
        throwUnsupported();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m) {
        throwUnsupported();
    }

    @Override
    public V getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue) {
        throwUnsupported();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void forEach(BiConsumer<? super K, ? super V> action) {
        throwUnsupported();
    }

    @Override
    public void replaceAll(BiFunction<? super K,
                                      ? super V, 
                                      ? extends V> function) {
        throwUnsupported();
    }

    @Override
    public V putIfAbsent(K key, V value) {
        throwUnsupported();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object key, Object value) {
        throwUnsupported();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean replace(K key, V oldValue, V newValue) {
        throwUnsupported();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public V replace(K key, V value) {
        throwUnsupported();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public V computeIfAbsent(K key, Function<? super K,
                                             ? extends V> mappingFunction) {    
        throwUnsupported();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public V computeIfPresent(K key, BiFunction<? super K,
                                                ? super V, 
                                                ? extends V>
                                                    remappingFunction) {    
        throwUnsupported();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public V compute(K key, BiFunction<? super K, 
                                       ? super V, 
                                       ? extends V> remappingFunction) {
        throwUnsupported();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public V merge(K key, V value, BiFunction<? super V, 
                                              ? super V,
                                              ? extends V> remappingFunction) {
        throwUnsupported();
        return null;    
    }

    private static void throwUnsupported() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(
                String.format(
                        "%s does not support this method.", 
                        SkipListMap.class.getName()));
    }
    
    private SkipListMapNode<K, V> accessNode(K searchKey) {
        
        Objects.requireNonNull(searchKey, "The input search key is null.");
        SkipListMapNode<K, V> x = header;
        
        for (int i = numberOfLevels - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            while (x.forward[i] != null && 
                   x.forward[i].key.compareTo(searchKey) < 0) {
                
                x = x.forward[i];
            }
        }
        
        x = x.forward[0];
        
        if (x == null) {
            return null;
        } 
        
        return x.key.equals(searchKey) ? x : null;
    }
    
    private int getRandomNumberOfLevels() {
        int newNumberOfLevels = 1;
        
        while (random.nextDouble() < p) {
            if (newNumberOfLevels == MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_LEVELS) {
                return MAXIMUM_NUMBER_OF_LEVELS;
            }
            
            newNumberOfLevels++;
        }
        
        return newNumberOfLevels;
    }
    
    private double validateCoinProbability(double p) {
        if (Double.isNaN(p)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input probability is NaN.");
        }
        
        return Math.min(MAXIMUM_COIN_PROBABILITY, Math.max(MINIMUM_COIN_PROBABILITY, p));
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.util.benchmark.SkipListMapBenchmark.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util.benchmark;

import com.github.coderodde.util.SkipListMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public final class SkipListMapBenchmark {
    
    private static final int MAP_SIZE = 10_000;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long seed = parseSeed(args);
        double coinProbability = parseCoinProbability(args);
        coinProbability = 0.25;
        seed = 1709125105008L;
        System.out.printf("Seed = %d.\n", seed);
        System.out.printf("Coin probability = %f.\n", coinProbability);
        
        Random random = new Random(seed);
        
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(MAP_SIZE);
        
        for (int i = 0; i < MAP_SIZE; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        
        Collections.shuffle(list, random);
        
        SkipListMap<Integer, Long> skipListMap = 
                new SkipListMap<>(coinProbability, random);
        
        TreeMap<Integer, Long> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();
        
        long totalSkipListMap = 0L;
        long totalTreeMap = 0L;
        
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        for (Integer key : list) {
            skipListMap.put(key, Long.valueOf(key));
        }
        
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        totalSkipListMap += end - start;
        
        System.out.printf("SkipListMap.put in %d milliseconds.\n",
                          end - start);
        
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        for (Integer key : list) {
            treeMap.put(key, Long.valueOf(key));
        }
        
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        totalTreeMap += end - start;
        
        System.out.printf("TreeMap.put in %d milliseconds.\n",
                          end - start);
        
        Collections.shuffle(list, random);
        
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        for (Integer key : list) {
            skipListMap.get(key);
        }
        
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        totalSkipListMap += end - start;
        
        System.out.printf("SkipListMap.get %d milliseconds.\n",
                          end - start);
        
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        for (Integer key : list) {
            treeMap.get(key);
        }
        
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        totalTreeMap += end - start;
        
        System.out.printf("TreeMap.get %d milliseconds.\n",
                          end - start);
        
        Collections.shuffle(list, random);
        
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        for (Integer key : list) {
            skipListMap.remove(key);
        }
        
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        totalSkipListMap += end - start;
        
        System.out.printf("SkipListMap.remove %d milliseconds.\n",
                          end - start);
        
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        for (Integer key : list) {
            treeMap.remove(key);
        }
        
        end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        
        totalTreeMap += end - start;
        
        System.out.printf("TreeMap.remove %d milliseconds.\n",
                          end - start);
        
        System.out.printf("SkipListMap total: %d milliseconds.\n",
                          totalSkipListMap);
        
        System.out.printf("TreeMap total: %d milliseconds.\n",
                          totalTreeMap);
    }
    
    private static long parseSeed(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            return System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        
        try {
            return Long.parseLong(args[0]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            return System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }
    
    private static double parseCoinProbability(String[] args) {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            return SkipListMap.DEFAULT_COIN_PROBABILITY;
        }
        
        try {
            return Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
            return SkipListMap.DEFAULT_COIN_PROBABILITY;
        }
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.util.SkipListMapTest.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertFalse;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNull;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import org.junit.Test;

public final class SkipListMapTest {
    
    @Test
    public void put() {
        SkipListMap<Integer, String> map = new SkipListMap<>(0.5, 13L);
        
        assertNull(map.put(2, "2"));
        assertNull(map.put(4, "4"));
        assertNull(map.put(3, "3"));
        assertNull(map.put(1, "1"));
        
        assertEquals("1", map.get(1));
        assertEquals("2", map.get(2));
        assertEquals("3", map.get(3));
        assertEquals("4", map.get(4));
        
        assertNull(map.get(0));
        assertNull(map.get(5));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void remove() {
        SkipListMap<Integer, String> map = new SkipListMap<>(0.5, 13L);
        
        assertNull(map.remove(1));
        assertFalse(map.containsKey(1));
        
        assertNull(map.put(2, "2"));
        assertNull(map.put(4, "4"));
        assertNull(map.put(3, "3"));
        assertNull(map.put(1, "1"));
        
        assertEquals("1", map.get(1));
        assertEquals("2", map.get(2));
        assertEquals("3", map.get(3));
        assertEquals("4", map.get(4));
        
        assertEquals("2", map.remove(2));
        
        assertTrue(map.containsKey(1));
        assertFalse(map.containsKey(2));
        assertTrue(map.containsKey(3));
        assertTrue(map.containsKey(4));
        
        assertEquals("1", map.remove(1));
        
        assertFalse(map.containsKey(1));
        assertFalse(map.containsKey(2));
        assertTrue(map.containsKey(3));
        assertTrue(map.containsKey(4));
        
        assertNull(map.remove(-1));
        assertNull(map.remove(10));
        
        assertEquals("4", map.remove(4));
        
        assertFalse(map.containsKey(1));
        assertFalse(map.containsKey(2));
        assertTrue(map.containsKey(3));
        assertFalse(map.containsKey(4));
        
        assertNull(map.remove(-1));
        assertNull(map.remove(10));
        
        assertEquals("3", map.remove(3));
        
        assertFalse(map.containsKey(1));
        assertFalse(map.containsKey(2));
        assertFalse(map.containsKey(3));
        assertFalse(map.containsKey(4));
        
        assertNull(map.remove(-1));
        assertNull(map.remove(10));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void compareToTreeMapBruteForce() {
        Random random = new Random(13L);
        Map<Integer, Long> skipListMap = new SkipListMap<>(random);
        Map<Integer, Long> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();
        List<Integer> presentList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> missingList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            assertFalse(skipListMap.containsKey(i));
            assertFalse(treeMap.containsKey(i));
            assertNull(skipListMap.get(i));
            assertNull(treeMap.get(i));
            assertNull(skipListMap.remove(i));
            assertNull(treeMap.remove(i));
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            presentList.add(2 * i);
            missingList.add(2 * i + 1);
        }
        
        Collections.shuffle(presentList, random);
        
        for (Integer key : presentList) {
            long value = key;
            assertNull(skipListMap.put(key, value));
            assertNull(treeMap.put(key, value));
        }
        
        Collections.shuffle(presentList, random);
        
        for (Integer key : presentList) {
            Long value1 = skipListMap.get(key);
            Long value2 = treeMap.get(key);
            assertTrue(Objects.equals(value1, value2));
        }
        
        for (Integer key : missingList) {
            assertFalse(skipListMap.containsKey(key));
            assertFalse(treeMap.containsKey(key));
            assertNull(skipListMap.get(key));
            assertNull(treeMap.get(key));
            assertNull(skipListMap.remove(key));
            assertNull(treeMap.remove(key));
        }
        
        Collections.shuffle(presentList, random);
        
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = presentList.iterator();
        
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Integer key = iterator.next();
            
            Long value1 = skipListMap.remove(key);
            Long value2 = treeMap.remove(key);
            
            iterator.remove();
            
            assertEquals(value2, value1);
            assertTrue(equals(skipListMap, treeMap, presentList));
            
        }
    }
    
    private static boolean equals(Map<Integer, Long> map1, 
                                  Map<Integer, Long> map2,
                                  List<Integer> list) {
        
        if (map1.size() != map2.size()) {
            return false;
        }

        for (Integer key : list) {
            boolean has1 = map1.containsKey(key);
            boolean has2 = map2.containsKey(key);
            
            if (has1 == has2) {
                if (!map1.get(key).equals(map2.get(key))) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else if (has1 == false && has2 == false) {
                // Both do not contain 'key'!
            } else {
                // Once here, we have a mismatch:
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

### Typical benchmark output

```
Seed = 1709125105008.
Coin probability = 0,250000.
SkipListMap.put in 206 milliseconds.
TreeMap.put in 17 milliseconds.
SkipListMap.get 555 milliseconds.
TreeMap.get 8 milliseconds.
SkipListMap.remove 208 milliseconds.
TreeMap.remove 12 milliseconds.
SkipListMap total: 969 milliseconds.
TreeMap total: 37 milliseconds.
```

## Critique request

As you can see from the **Typical benchmark output**, skip list is way more slower than a red-black tree -based `java.util.TreeMap`. So, I am mainly interested how to make the skip list run faster.

Comment: Have you tried adding `ConcurrentSkipListMap` to the benchmark? It would be interesting to see how its performance compares to your implementation.

Comment: @morgwai Excellent idea! I will give it a try, thanks!

Comment: @morgwai You are right, `ConcurrentSkipListMap` is way more faster than mine attempt.